# Should we also have some chat events that are not about generating new answers or other "work" on the site?

Tags: discussion, events, chat

There's an active topic on the linguistics.SE meta site about whether they want to start scheduling regular chat events on linguistics topics.

Well that made me think, why don't we have regular online meet ups in our chat room here where we just do stuff like say hi to the new people and chat about the best new topics in our main site and our meta site, and probably the most controversial new topics too... And of course going off on whatever tangents.

More purely social chat events than "work" chat events.

What do others think?

Answer (score 2):

We have tried the occasional one, but with limited success.  However, that was a while ago.  I'm happy to try this - if you can start suggesting topics below?  And times (UMT)?  I'm happy to then start adding them.

Comment: Topics? The topics are the big new questions and answers and anything interesting or controversial that's happened on our site lately, or out in the world that's travel related.

Or do events have some kind of "topic" field? If so just "monthly get together" or such. Perhaps "regular" is the key. If people know we talk about "travel news" every Monday at 6pm GMT or whatever those interested will know to drop by.

Comment: true. I was thinking of having event topics - like #TTOT does on twitter - event travel, beach travel, family travel etc.

Comment: Sure we could have both topicful and topicless chats too (-: (I know nothing about Twitter other than it exists.)